# WebClient logging without deprecated method tcpClient.bootstrap()

Tags: java, reactor-netty

I'm trying do some logging in my middleware application, where I want to log request and response of backend system. I would like to use Netty (because we have implemented difficult SslContext).

I'm trying to learn it by this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls (chapter 4.2. Logging with Netty HttpClient).

For better looking logs, there is part of code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
  .create()
  .tcpConfiguration(
    tc -> tc.bootstrap(
      b -> BootstrapHandlers.updateLogSupport(b, new CustomLogger(HttpClient.class))))
  .build()
```

but `bootstrap(...)` method is deprecated. What can I use instead?

Comment: Do you need the `CustomLogger` only for request/response or also for some other events as channel registered/connected etc.?

Comment: Mainly for logging request/response, ideally with bodies

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jfsanchez91/e2fd588977ae6fbaf276ec3c813489f4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `CustomLogger` for request/response (as per comment above) then you can do the following:

```
CustomLogger customLogger = new CustomLogger(HttpClient.class);         
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                .create()
                .doOnRequest((request, connection) -> {
                    connection.addHandlerFirst(customLogger);
                });
```

Comment: I have a same code and this solution is not working for me. However, solution Violeta wrote on github is working. That is adding .wiretap("netty-external-client-logger", LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL) to the HttpClient, and adding property logging.level.netty-external-client-logger = INFO to application.properties file. btw: "netty-external-client-logger" is my internal name for this property. You can set there whatever you want. It is only important to be the same inside HttpClient definition and inside application.properties file.